# Swap Method of a linked list in java, which values change

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a method to swap adjacent values in a linked list, and I'm confused about what happens when you set values equal to one another. For example, say I have a linked list, and I want to swap the elements at index 4 and 5 (say the list has 10 elements).
If I use the code:

```
Node tempAt = getNode(4);
Node tempPost = getNode(5);
getNode(3).next = tempPost;
tempAt.next = tempPost.next;
tempPost.next = getNode(3);
```

Does this work? Basically, I'm getting mixed up with variables. When you set one node equal to another (Ex: `Node temp = listHead`), is temp essentially the same as the node listHead? If I modify `listHead`, will `temp` be modified as well?
EDIT:
Also, if I create something like: `Node temp = listHead`, and then change the value of `listHead.next`, what will be the value of `temp.next`?

Comment: *Does this work?* -> Well, try it out, and see.

Comment: `Does this work?` Why not try that out?

Comment: The code was just to illustrate what I mean. I'm the most confused about the last part of the post ( the edit)

Answer (score 0):

In your edit, `Node temp = listHead`.  `temp` is a variable that holds the value of `listHead`.  `listHead` has a field called next, which is also a variable holding a value to another node.  When you change  `listHead.next`, you are changing the value of the field `next` in the object `listHead`, and `temp`'s value is still the object `listHead`, so when you say `temp.next`, that is equal to `listHead.next`.

You can read [this article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) if you want to know more about how Java is pass by value.